# How can i create a sum and display it from a Database value?

Tags: javascript, events, firebase-realtime-database, sum, dom-events

I am using a Firebase db. I have a value `i` display on my page that increments and updates itself which can be seen on the web page.
I also have predetermined *total* value.
I want to create a sum that has the total value be decreased by the previously mentioned dynamic value. and send an alert to the user on the web page when it hits 0.

However I can't seem to get this to work, this is what I tried:

```
// here I  create the sum for the total amount
var total = 0;
function getData(){
    for (var i = 0; i < HoeveelheidArr.length; i++) { //my arrawy from user input which i extracted
       total += parseInt(HoeveelheidArr[i]);
    }
}

//here i push the values to my DB
function writeData(){
    firebase.database().ref("Exercise").set({
        totalReps: total,
        totalRepsLeft: progressLeft,
    });

    //Here I update the DYNAMIC value on my page it gets incremented by 1 by my arduino on an event. this works
    var progressList = document.getElementById("progressList");
    var wemosRep = function(element, value){
        element.textContent = value;
    }
    //get value from db and auto pass update if change in value
    var startWemosRep = firebase.database().ref('Reps/Value');
    startWemosRep.on('value', function(snapshot){
        wemosRep(progressList,snapshot.val());
    });

    //now the part that doesnt work... Just like before I try to first create the sum and then display it on my page if this value changed.
    progressLeft = parseInt( startWemosRep) - total  ; //this doesnt!

    var pageProgressLeft = document.getElementById("progressLeft");
    var repLeft = function (element, value){
        element.textContent = value;
    };

    var startTotalRep = firebase.database().ref('Exercise/progressLeft');
    startTotalRep.on('value', function(snapshot){
        repLeft(pageProgressLeft, snapshot.val());
    });
}


// I get the total value i pushed in my DB named totalGet!
function gotData(data){
  firebase.database().ref('Exercise').once('value').then (function(snapshot){
      var totalGet = snapshot.val().totalReps;
      document.getElementById("totalList").innerHTML=totalGet;

})
```

The `progressLeft` variable doesn't get returned, that is what it boils down to. It doesn't display on my page nor do I know if it works. I tried everything at this point I cant see the end of the tunnel. Hope you can help me out with this.